# Конструкция fetch в fetch

Tags: javascript, json, api, promise, fetch

Есть у меня подобная конструкция. Не понимаю, как сделать так, чтобы после получения информации со второго `fetch` можно было бы использовать как и `data1`, так и `data2` между собой. Например, вложить одно в другое. Потому что если отконсолить `data1` во втором `fetch`, то он её не видит

```
function getData() {
    fetch(api1, {method: 'get'})
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(function (data1) {
            return fetch(api2, {method: 'get'})
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(function (data2) {
            console.log(data1);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log('Причина ошибки: ' + error));
}

getData();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если оба запроса независимы друг от друга и нужно получить данные из обоих, плюс ко всему [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) возвращает `promise`, то я бы использовал в данном случае метод [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). Пример кода:

```
function getData() {
  var getDataFirst = fetch(api1, {method: 'get'})
    .then(response => response.json());

  var getDataSecond = fetch(api2, {method: 'get'})
    .then(response => response.json());

  Promise.all([getDataFirst, getDataSecond])
    .then(
      values => { 
        console.log(values);
      },
      reason => {
        console.log(reason);
      }
    );
}
```

`Promise.all` ждет выполнения всех обещаний (или первого метода `reject`). В результате также возвращает [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), который будет выполнен когда будут выполнены все обещания, и в `values` - будут лежать все Ваши результаты в виде массива из двух значений.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что Вы два последних `then` читаете с первого `fetch` Попробуйте сделать так:

```js
function getData() {
    fetch(api1, {method: 'get'})
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(function (data1) {
            fetch(api2, {method: 'get'})
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(function (data2) {
                  console.log(data1);
              })
              .catch(error => console.log('Причина ошибки: ' + error));
        })
        .catch(error => console.log('Причина ошибки: ' + error));
}

getData();
```

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, с then'ами легко запутаться, поэтому и придумали `async`/`await`:

```js
async function getData() {
    try {
        let response = await fetch(api1, {method: 'get'});
        const data1 = await response.json();
        response = await fetch(api2, {method: 'get'});
        const data2 = await response.json();
        console.log(data1, data2);
    } catch(error) {
        console.log('Причина ошибки: ' + error));
    } 
}
```