# Правильное использование fetch

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

По условию задачи есть массив данных с пользователями и условный api "https://", проверяющий онлайн ли пользователь по id (возвращает true или false). Необходимо вывести новый массив данных, включающий isOnline для каждого пользователя. Можно ли назвать решение верным и как можно его оптимизировать?

```
      const people = [{ name: "Vlad", id: 1 }, { name: "Victor", id: 2 }];

      function getOnline() {
        const newArr = [...people];
        people.forEach((item, index) => {

          fetch(`https://${item.id}`)
            .then((response) => {
              return response.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {//true/false
              newArr[index].isOnline = data;
            });
            
        });
        return newArr;
      }

      console.log(getOnline());
```

Comment: вообще то неверно

Comment: @AzizUmarov, почему неверно?

Comment: @Grundy потому это JS. и нужно понимать асинхронное программирование.

Comment: Вы почти справились с задачей. Единственное, что не получилось *вывести новый массив данных, включающий isOnline для каждого пользователя*.

Comment: @AzizUmarov, а что тут не по асинхронному? :)

Answer (score 2):

Для наглядности я добавил в код квази-fetch, который 1) асинхронный, 2) нормально применим в вашем коде.

```js
const people = [
  { name: "Vlad", id: 1 },
  { name: "Victor", id: 2 }
];

const res = getOnline(people);
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));


function getOnline(peopleList) {
  const newArr = [...peopleList];

  people.forEach((item, index) => {

    fetch(`https://${item.id}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => newArr[index].isOnline = data);

  });

  return newArr;
}

function fetch() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({
        json: () => Promise.resolve(false)
      });
    }, 100 * Math.random());
  });
}
```

При запуске вашей функции возвращается массив в котором нет ключей `isOnline` так как асинхронный `fetch` не выполнился к моменту вывода данных в лог. `getOnline` выполнился в синхронном режиме, вернув "новый" массив и запустив ряд асинхронных операций, при этом не дождался выполнения этих всех асинхронных операций.

> Можно ли назвать решение верным и как можно его оптимизировать?

Отвечая на ваш вопрос, *нельзя назвать ваше решение верным*. Прочитайте ещё раз все простые учебные материалы про Promise, обратите внимание на Promise.all. После этого попробуйте переделать решение.

Про оптимизацию писать пока не буду так как бессмысленно заниматься ею пока нет верного решения.

Comment: так как меняется объект, то в момент просмотра в консоли результат вполне верным может быть :)

Comment: @Grundy не успеет стать "верным", я поставил задержку не менее 100ms

Comment: Еще можно добавить, что при достаточном размере массива `people`, этот код превращается в DOS-атаку. :)

Comment: @Yaant я решил в ответе не рассматривать ничего, что было бы связано с "оптимизацией" так как, увы, [топикстартер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/336121/anna?tab=questions) уже год как задаёт однообразные [вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1026840/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-fetch-%d0%b2-fetch) и всё никак не разберётся с самой сутью промисов и колбэков

Comment: @nörbörnën, не, я имел ввиду, если не использовать `JSON.stringify` при выводе

Comment: @Grundy тэк! останешься после уроков - будем решать Сканави